# Vosk / porcupine fehler

Tags: python, pycharm, vosk

I have a problem with Vosk a. Porcupine
the console :

```
[2021-02-26 07:44:44.413060] Detected porcupine
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jens\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\porcupine_demo_mic.py", line 210, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\jens\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\porcupine_demo_mic.py", line 200, in main
    PorcupineDemo(
  File "C:\Users\jens\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\porcupine_demo_mic.py", line 110, in run
    if rec.AcceptWaveform(pcm):
  File "C:\Users\jens\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\vosk\__init__.py", line 58, in AcceptWaveform
    return _c.vosk_recognizer_accept_waveform(self._handle, data, len(data))
TypeError: initializer for ctype 'char' must be a bytes of length 1, not int
```

my code:

```
class PorcupineDemo(Thread):

    def __init__(
            self,
            library_path,
            model_path,
            keyword_paths,
            sensitivities,
            input_device_index=None,
            output_path=None):

        """
        Constructor.

        :param library_path: Absolute path to Porcupine's dynamic library.
        :param model_path: Absolute path to the file containing model parameters.
        :param keyword_paths: Absolute paths to keyword model files.
        :param sensitivities: Sensitivities for detecting keywords. Each value should be a number within [0, 1]. A
        higher sensitivity results in fewer misses at the cost of increasing the false alarm rate. If not set 0.5 will
        be used.
        :param input_device_index: Optional argument. If provided, audio is recorded from this input device. Otherwise,
        the default audio input device is used.
        :param output_path: If provided recorded audio will be stored in this location at the end of the run.
        """

        super(PorcupineDemo, self).__init__()

        self._library_path = library_path
        self._model_path = model_path
        self._keyword_paths = keyword_paths
        self._sensitivities = sensitivities
        self._input_device_index = input_device_index

        self._output_path = output_path
        if self._output_path is not None:
            self._recorded_frames = []

    def run(self):
        """
         Creates an input audio stream, instantiates an instance of Porcupine object, and monitors the audio stream for
         occurrences of the wake word(s). It prints the time of detection for each occurrence and the wake word.
         """

        keywords = list()
        for x in self._keyword_paths:
            keywords.append(os.path.basename(x).replace('.ppn', '').split('_')[0])

        porcupine = None
        pa = None
        audio_stream = None

        model = Model('C:/Users/jens/PycharmProjects/pythonProject2/german-vosk-model')
        rec = KaldiRecognizer(model, 16000)

        try:
            porcupine = pvporcupine.create(
                library_path=self._library_path,
                model_path=self._model_path,
                keyword_paths=self._keyword_paths,
                sensitivities=self._sensitivities)

            pa = pyaudio.PyAudio()

            audio_stream = pa.open(
                rate=porcupine.sample_rate,
                channels=1,
                format=pyaudio.paInt16,
                input=True,
                frames_per_buffer=porcupine.frame_length,
                input_device_index=self._input_device_index)

            print('Listening {')
            for keyword, sensitivity in zip(keywords, self._sensitivities):
                print('  %s (%.2f)' % (keyword, sensitivity))
            print('}')

            is_installing = False

            while True:
                pcm = audio_stream.read(porcupine.frame_length)
                pcm = struct.unpack_from("h" * porcupine.frame_length, pcm)

                if self._output_path is not None:
                    self._recorded_frames.append(pcm)

                result = porcupine.process(pcm)
                if result >= 0:
                    is_installing = True
                    print('[%s] Detected %s' % (str(datetime.now()), keywords[result]))

                if is_installing:
                    if rec.AcceptWaveform(pcm):
                        recResult = json.loads(rec.Result())
                        print(recResult['text'])
                        is_installing = False

        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print('Stopping ...')
        finally:
            if porcupine is not None:
                porcupine.delete()

            if audio_stream is not None:
                audio_stream.close()

            if pa is not None:
                pa.terminate()

            if self._output_path is not None and len(self._recorded_frames) > 0:
                recorded_audio = np.concatenate(self._recorded_frames, axis=0).astype(np.int16)
                soundfile.write(self._output_path, recorded_audio, samplerate=porcupine.sample_rate, subtype='PCM_16')

    @classmethod
    def show_audio_devices(cls):
        fields = ('index', 'name', 'defaultSampleRate', 'maxInputChannels')

        pa = pyaudio.PyAudio()

        for i in range(pa.get_device_count()):
            info = pa.get_device_info_by_index(i)
            print(', '.join("'%s': '%s'" % (k, str(info[k])) for k in fields))

        pa.terminate()


def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

    parser.add_argument(
        '--keywords',
        nargs='+',
        help='List of default keywords for detection. Available keywords: %s' % ', '.join(sorted(pvporcupine.KEYWORDS)),
        choices=sorted(pvporcupine.KEYWORDS),
        metavar='')

    parser.add_argument(
        '--keyword_paths',
        nargs='+',
        help="Absolute paths to keyword model files. If not set it will be populated from `--keywords` argument")

    parser.add_argument('--library_path', help='Absolute path to dynamic library.', default=pvporcupine.LIBRARY_PATH)

    parser.add_argument(
        '--model_path',
        help='Absolute path to the file containing model parameters.',
        default=pvporcupine.MODEL_PATH)

    parser.add_argument(
        '--sensitivities',
        nargs='+',
        help="Sensitivities for detecting keywords. Each value should be a number within [0, 1]. A higher " +
             "sensitivity results in fewer misses at the cost of increasing the false alarm rate. If not set 0.5 " +
             "will be used.",
        type=float,
        default=None)

    parser.add_argument('--audio_device_index', help='Index of input audio device.', type=int, default=None)

    parser.add_argument('--output_path', help='Absolute path to recorded audio for debugging.', default=None)

    parser.add_argument('--show_audio_devices', action='store_true')

    args = parser.parse_args()

    if args.show_audio_devices:
        PorcupineDemo.show_audio_devices()
    else:
        if args.keyword_paths is None:
            if args.keywords is None:
                raise ValueError("Either `--keyword` or `--keyword_paths` must be set.")

            keyword_paths = [pvporcupine.KEYWORD_PATHS[x] for x in args.keywords]
        else:
            keyword_paths = args.keyword_paths('jarvis')

        if args.sensitivities is None:
            args.sensitivities = [0.5] * len(keyword_paths)

        if len(keyword_paths) != len(args.sensitivities):
            raise ValueError('Number of keywords does not match the number of sensitivities.')

        PorcupineDemo(
            library_path=args.library_path,
            model_path=args.model_path,
            keyword_paths=keyword_paths,
            sensitivities=args.sensitivities,
            output_path=args.output_path,
            input_device_index=args.audio_device_index).run()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Okay, so what is your *question*? Did you read the documentation? Did you check that the `pcm` data you pass to `rec.AcceptWaveform` is formatted the way you expected, and the way that the documentation says is required? Please read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and ask a specific question that explains where something different happens from what you expect to happen, and why you expect the other thing to happen.

Comment: My questuon ist i dont now what i must to do to fix the error end i need help to fix the error : TypeError: initializer for ctype 'char' must be a bytes of length 1, not int
everything is actually correct

Comment: hat sich geklärt